# How to use spring batch composite reader to perform join query?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-batch

Now I have three big mysql tables:

```
geo_ip: [start_ip, end_ip, country_code, region_code, city], 
region: [region_code, region_name], 
country: [country_code, country_name]
```

I want to design a spring batch step which reads three tables and generate record containing [start_ip, end_ip, country_code, country_name, region_code, region_name, city]

If I use a single reader which performs a join of the three tables, it will be super slow. Is there a way to use composite reader and can be much faster than joining the tables?

Comment: What prevents you from using a simple SQL JOIN?

Comment: @MichaelPralow Because it is super slow and tables are big

Comment: did you test it? the tables look rather simple, even with millions of entries it should not take long to build the cursor (on the database side)